# In ZF2 manipulate the response

Tags: php, zend-framework2, httpresponse

I am developing rest web services using zend 2.
For error handling I am using below mentioned code in Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, array(
            $this,
            'onDispatchError'
        ), 0);
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER_ERROR, array(
            $this,
            'onRenderError'
        ), 0);
    }

    public function onDispatchError($e)
    {
        return $this->getJsonModelError($e);
    }

    public function onRenderError($e)
    {
        return $this->getJsonModelError($e);
    }

    /*
     * Manages error's and return response_code and error message
     *
     * @return Zend\View\Model\JsonModel
     */
    public function getJsonModelError($e)
    {
        $error = $e->getError();

        if (! $error) {
            return;
        }
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        $sm = StaticServiceManager::getDefaultServiceManager();
        $config = $sm->get('config');

        $err_code = $response->getStatusCode();
        $err_msg = $response->getReasonPhrase();
        $response_code = $config['HTTP_ERROR'][$err_code]['response_code'];
        $errorJson = array(
            'response_code' => $response_code,
            // 'status' => $err_code,
            'message' => $err_msg
        );
        $model = new JsonModel($errorJson);

        $e->setResult($model);

        return $model;
    }
```

However there are still cases which are not tracked by this approach. For e.g. Invalid HTTP method passed. Does there any way I can check final response and manipulate it e.g. I can check final response content-type & http status code to finally change the response to send some meaning full json message.

Comment: I had written like this https://github.com/biberlabs/zf2-boilerplate/blob/master/module/Api/Module.php#L64 I dont know, it was different.

Comment: You can check it for Api System.

Comment: hkulekci
That part I understand but what if your bootstrap method is not even get initiated, for e.g. if I send a request with request method COPY  my bootstrap method is not get loaded and show below error

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Http\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid HTTP method passed' in /var/www/html/ggp3/rest-services/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Http/Request.php